# If people have put answers as comments, is it OK for me to copy their comment to an answer myself?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

I encountered a question where a person had put an answer in the comments, then the OP had commented again saying that answer worked, and thanks.

[Here was the specific question, but I am asking in a general sense](https://askubuntu.com/questions/985384/cannot-execute-any-files-from-separate-home-partition).

I commented to remind people to make proper answers instead of leaving the answers in the comments.

BUT:

Would it have been OK for me to copy the correct answer from the comment to a new answer of my own, in order to solve the problem immediately?  I wouldn't be doing it to claim credit, but because having a correct answer buried in the comments is not good for people browsing the site.

Comment: FWIW the OP just invited me to add it as an answer myself so I did.

Comment: This is called plagiarism and it is usually frowned upon.